# Error of compilation after add firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, firebase-cloud-messaging

For an applications development I need firebase cloud messaging.
In my pubsepc.yaml I add this dependencies : firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6

I don't have add code for the moment.

Afterward I build code and I have error  :

```
flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:143: error: method findAppBundlePath in class FlutterMain cannot be applied to given types;
    String appBundlePath = FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath();
                                      ^
  required: Context
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you added android integration described at the package readme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to Java and check `FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java`

```
FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath()
```

it required context in the argument here so 1st solution is here you can add context in the argument like this way

```
FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(context)
```

The second solution remove `firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6` dependency from `pubspac.yaml` and hit `flutter clean` in terminal to clean, now add `firebase_messaging: 5.1.6` **(without ^)** and hit `flutter pub get` in terminal. This solution works for me.

**The second solution is the better practice.**

Comment: Thanks, It's work for me. But I change the versions to firebase_messaging: 5.0.0.

Comment: The second solution is work for me, then execute Flutter Upgrade option on the pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Maddy is clear. But if someone is not solved the problem.

Please try: `flutter upgrade` and do @Maddy answer

This works for me. 
Sorry about new thread answer, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: You should post your answer as a comment under @Maddy answer